# Find out extension of executable files?

Tags: compiling, executable, make, configure, portability

When I am building software from source on a GNU+Linux system, during the `./configure` stage I frequently see the following line:

```
checking for suffix of executables...
```

How do I create such a check in a bash script?

The reason I want to know this is that I want to create a makefile in which it compiles with suffix .exe on Cygwin, but no suffix on true GNU+Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test is done by compiling a small dummy C program and by checking how the compiler names the output file.

The following example is a **simplified** version of what `configure` is doing

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOT > dummy.c
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    return 0;
}
EOT

gcc -o dummy dummy.c

if [ -f dummy.exe ] ; then
  # exe
fi
```

I would suggest you to use autoconf to generate a configure script and use it for your purpose.

Comment: However, if someone places a file called `dummy.exe` in the local directory but the system is actually GNU+Linux, won't this say "exe" instead of "no extension"?

Comment: @MuhammadMoazImtiaz Sure as I said this is an a simplified example. You could create a unique temporary file with `mktemp` and delete it afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

This will give you the extension of the file:

```
FILENAME=/tmp/testfile.exe
echo "${FILENAME##*.}"
```

result:

```
exe
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The configure script tests which is the default for an unknown system. In your case you are just retrieving the extension for a known file. And moreover your code fails if the file does not have an extension.

Comment: But isn't he asking for a bash script solution?

Comment: Yes and this is exactly what `configure` (a bash script) is doing. Calling gcc in a script or calling ls is the same thing both are executable.

Comment: Clearly out of my depth here, I should write (and compile) some more code. Thanks Matteo.